# Linux shell script for selecting output as a directory path

Tags: shell, scripting

I have a script which take a path of a folder as an argument and a path for the output.

> Ex- Myscript.sh /bin/apps/sample /bin/apps/
>
> Input - /bin/apps/sample ($1)
>
> Output - /bin/apps/ ($2)

Now the output should always be stored in `/bin/apps/` i.e. one directory backwards of input directory. Please remember that the input and output directory paths vary as per user so I need a universal code which can perform the following operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dirname` to get the parent directory of your input path:

```
#! /bin/bash

INPUT=$1
if [ ! -d "${INPUT}" ]; then
    echo "invalid input directory '${INPUT}'" >&2
    exit 1
fi

OUTPUT=$(dirname "${INPUT}")

echo "[${INPUT}]" "[${OUTPUT}]"
```